# How to change navigation bar background in Flutter for white color?

Tags: flutter, navigation, background-color

I am trying to set my navigation bar background to while, but instead I am getting light grey that is default as I understand

[image]

Here is how I declared background in the code

```
     NavigationBar(

      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFFFF),
```

But If I use dark shades it works well:

[image]

```
          NavigationBar(
               backgroundColor: Colors.black,
```

Does anyone know why it can be the case?

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't it be 0xFFFFFFFF for black?

Answer (score 2):

Also add surfaceTintColor
Example:

```
 backgroundColor: Colors.white,
 surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your Hexadecimal color value has 2 more **FF** than what is necessary.
So, instead of **0xFFFFFFFFFF** it should be **0xFFFFFFFF**

And, instead of:

```
  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
```

You can use:

```
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
```

Comment: Thank you very much for suggestion, but it didn't work for me. Even though I changed color to Colors.white it is still grey :(

Comment: @ElenaEpshtein are you defining any theme in your app? If so, it might be forcing some of the colors. Either that or the **NavigtionBar**  has some opacity in it.